# Auto Start a .py file with LXTerminal

Tags: raspbian, python, script, lxterminal

I want to start a .py file after booting with LXTerminal. I'm using raspbian OS I try these steps:

I edited

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

with

```
@lxterminal
```

and this is open automatically terminal it is good. After that I editted as:

```
@lxterminal -e /usr/bin/python /home/pi/myscript.py
```

and this is not working on me. LXTerminal didn't open. So my program didn't run

Can you help me?

Comment: It may be a language barrier but I honestly don't understand what your are asking? You want upon booting the raspberry pi to open a terminal window and execute a .py script.?

Answer (score 0):

Is the script executable and have you included '#!/usr/bin/env python' on the top line of the script?
If not, that should fix it.